# Filling Java 2D array input

Tags: java, arrays, input

I am trying to get user input in a 2D array. I would like not to use `java.util.Arrays` if possible.

User input looks like this, the first integer being the number, the second the index of the integer.

```
3 3
1 2
3 2
```

This is what I get

```
[3,3,1][2,3,2][][][][]
```

This is what I would like to get

```
[][1,3][3][][][]
```

---

```
int x = sc.nextInt();
int array[][] = new int[6][x];

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++ ){
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
        array[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
    }   
}

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

Comment: what is the logic between input and the output?

Comment: First int being the number, second index of the int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you mean format:

```
number index_to_add
```

This is not simple, because you don't know, how many numbers will be in array at start.

I would use a collection like `ArrayList` etc.

If you really want to use just arrays, you have to have a top limit.

ArrayList version:

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] list = new ArrayList<Integer>[6];

//init
for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    list[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

//fill
while(sc.hasNextInt()){
    int number = sc.nextInt();
    if(sc.hasNextInt()){
        int index_to_add = sc.nextInt();
        list[index_to_add].add(number);
    }else{
        break;
    }
}
```

Note: code not tested;

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already have a version with Arrays completed and working. I was just wondering if it is possible to do without them. I guess I will be using them.

Comment: If you want to use array, you have to know, how many numbers will be inserted in each subarray. Then, you have to have another array (1D), where will be stored indexes of last insertions - you have to know on which index you will put your integer. This is not much ellegant. Collections will be better in this case. Answer to your question "Is it possible to do without them?". My answer: surely it is, but it will be reinventing a wheel - you will implement LinkedList or something simmilar on your own :P @OhOkay